# Running a bash shell from a flash drive

Tags: linux, bash, usb, shell

I was wondering if it was possible to have a bash shell (and relevant commands) runnable from a USB flash drive.

I'm not really talking about a bootable Linux version from a USB, but rather a "plug this in while Windows is on to have a working bash shell on Windows, without actually installing anything on the Windows system". Is this doable? Would I need to compile the shell and other programs depending on the OS I plug it into?

I was thinking of something similar to those mini-browsers you can run off of a USB without actually installing anything to Windows.

Comment: You can use a fully installed cygwin/mingw environment on your usb flash, then simply execute `bash.exe`.

Comment: @IporSircer will that work for all versions of Windows with a single installation?

Comment: i think yes (from winxp), but you can check anytime cygwin/mingw homepage for compatibilities.

Comment: @IporSircer, add it as an answer, It'll get you some points!